# Probability notation(a function of distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a RV $ X \sim Q$ and wants to denote the probability under Q of the event E. 
Obviously, I can use $ P(E) $ but I want to emphasis the distribution so I want to use $ Q(E) $.
I thought that it is a standard notation but don't seems to see it anywhere. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It is standard. Or you can use $P_X$

Comment: It is a perfect valid notation and used plentifully. If you want to see it used, see e.g. the book [Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/arbitrage-theory-in-continuous-time-9780199574742?cc=dk&lang=en&) by Thomas Björk.

Comment: The setting you describe seems slightly absurd since the term "event" usually refers to subsets of the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ the random variable $X$ is defined on, while $Q$ the distribution of $X$, is by definition a measure on the image set of $X$, usually the measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. Hence $Q(E)$ is simply undefined for $E$ in $\mathcal F$ (except if it happens that $(\Omega,\mathcal F)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, naturally). Please explain.

Comment: I am dealing with discrete spaces. I have a finite set $\cal{X}$ and "events" are subsets of $\cal{X}$